# Adapter pattern in C++ using mix of private and public inheritance

Tags: c++, c++11, adapter, unique-lock

I have a question about creating a lock adapter, and more generally the adapter pattern with style of implementation below. The implementation below based on the answer in
[Proper C++ way of implementing a lock_guard for custom library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42618868/proper-c-way-of-implementing-a-lock-guard-for-custom-library). The implementation relies on public inheritance of the new interface (class in this case) and private inheritance of the legacy interface. However there doesn't seem to be a clean way of passing the lock_adapter to unique_lock, i.e. since adapted_unique_lock *is not* a lock_adapter as the author might have intended, i.e. this does not compile.

```
template<class T>
struct lock_adapter {
  T* t = nullptr;
  void lock() { t->Lock(); }
  void unlock() { t->Unlock(); }
  lock_adapter( T& tin ):t(std::addressof(tin)) {}
  // default some stuff if you like
};

template<class T>
struct adapted_unique_lock:
  private lock_adapter<T>,
  std::unique_lock< lock_adapter<T> >
{
  template<class...Args>
  adapted_unique_lock(T& t, Args&&...):
    lock_adapter<T>(t),
    std::unique_lock< lock_adapter<T> >( *this, std::forward<Args>(args)... )
  {}
  adapted_unique_lock(adapted_unique_lock&&)=delete; // sadly
  friend void swap( adapted_unique_lock&, adapted_unique_lock& ) = delete; // ditto
};
```

For this specific instance, doing something simple instead such as below works with direct adaptation of unique_lock.

```
struct L1
{
    void Lock(){}
    void Unlock() {}
};


 void test()
 {
     L1 l;
     lock_adapter<L1> l_adapt(l);
     unique_lock<lock_adapter<L1>> u(l_adapt)
 }
```

My question is if there is a way to get the original implementation that uses a mix of private and public inheritance working which would need for the private base to be passed into the public base class?

Comment: `std::unique_lock` is not meant to be derived from. I don't understand what `adapted_unique_lock` is supposed to achieve. That said, you can make it compile with a cast: `static_cast<lock_adapter<T>&>(*this)` in place of `*this`. [Demo](https://rextester.com/JRXJNJ61382)

Comment: Thanks Igor. Because lock_adapter<T> is inherited privately, IOW does not follow the is-a relationship of public inheritance, is constructing unique_lock<lock_adapter<T>> with **this* still appropriate?

Comment: `lock_adapter<T>` here is essentially a data member. The only reason to make it a private base class instead is to ensure that it's constructed first, before `unique_lock`. `adapted_unique_lock` does not rely on is-a relationship or anything like that - just on having a sub-object of type `lock_adapter<T>`. The fact that this sub-object is accessed via a quirky syntax like `static_cast<lock_adapter<T>&>(*this)` is not really relevant.